# How to configure an autorun.inf file?

Tags: windows-7, autorun

I was wondering if I can create an autorun.inf file that does not run an .exe file. Intstead, it can open up a web browser or plays a video. How do I go about doing these steps? Of course, I do know that some .inf files can be detected as a virus, but this autorun.inf file I wish to do is clean.

Advice on how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

basically, everything you put in the `open=` portion of the .inf will be opened with the default associated application, or executed.

If you put a web address in there like this :

```
open=http://www.google.com
```

it will open google.com in the system's default web browser.

you can (of course) always check the docs Microsoft provides.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks for the quick reply. I will check that site out, I hope it has everything I need to know to make this work :)
**EDIT:** This website is for CD-ROM. Does it work for thumb drive as well?

Comment: It should, autorun.inf is the same for all removable media.

Comment: Hi, I tested this out yesterday and it didn't work. No idea why, but it just won't autorun. Does the branding of the USB Thumb drive matters??

Comment: When you mount a drive or CD in Windows, since windows XP, Windows then shows a dialog.
Since Windows 7, this dialog be suppressed on Cds and DVDs, but not on thumb drives.
On earlier versions, it *can* be suppressed.
If the settings on your computer are set do "do nothing" when a usb drive is inserted ; nothing will happen at all.
For more info, read: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive.htm

Comment: The branding of the drive should have no impact at all.